# Unable to complete installation on Windows 10

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am not familiar with linux or much of the jargon that I see on the site, which is probably at the root of my problem.

I downloaded an iso image of UBUNTU-16.04.1-desktop-amd64, and burned it to a DVD.

I am using an HP Envy laptop running Windows 10. In restarting the laptop, I have modified the settings so that it will boot from the CD, which appears to be working successfully. The boot process seems extremely slow, but it does boot.

I get the initial menu of trying Ubuntu without installing, install it, OEM install, or check disc for defects, and select "Install Ubuntu".

A screen pops up with Ubuntu and 5 lights indicating it is doing something.

I get a message about Wifi networks being available, and connect.

The next screen asks if I want to download updates and install 3rd party software, both are selected.

I've never seen a screen as illustrated in the installation documents that allows you to replace everything on the hard disk with Ubuntu, which is what I'd like to do.

The next screen is where everything stops without a clue about what to do, it is labeled "Installation type".

There is an empty panel with: Device, Type, Mount point, Format?, Size, Used, and System as headings. There is no content in the panel. There are "+", "-", and "Change..." buttons below the panel. The "+" and "-" buttons don't do anything, and the "Change..." button is disabled. There are also "New Partition Table..." and "Revert" buttons, also disabled. The net result is an empty panel which does nothing that is apparent.

There is a drop-down control labeled: "Device for boot loader installation:" It has "/dev/sda" as the first and only item. Again, clicking on it does nothing.

The window buttons at the bottom are "Quit", "Back", and "Install Now". The "Install Now" button worked the first time, and I got a message that said, "No root file system is defined. Please correct from partitioning menu."

Since that error, the "Install Now" button no longer works. The "Back" button does not work. The "Quit" button does not work. My assumption is the partitioning menu is the empty panel that doesn't work.

I finally get a screen that says "Install (as superuser) is not responding, with my choices of waiting or force the application to quit.

I would appreciate some help, but may not be able to understand a response filled with acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark 1 of the partitions you want to install on as `/` and as `ext4` before you can proceed.

Example:

[image]

The image I got from this [tutorial](http://ivanblagojevic.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-an-empty-hard-disk-tutorial/).

Regarding the numbers:

First, create the root partition.
Ignore the values in the pictures, because the installation is done in VirtualBox, but follow the instructions.

9. Size: The best and most economical way to assign 10,000 to 20,000 MB. Less than 10 GB is perhaps not enough if you plan a lot of applications.
10. Select Primary type for new partition
11. Select beginning of this space
12. Select from the dropdawn menu Ext4 journaling file system
13. Select from the dropdawn menu or enter by hand: /

/ is the mount point for root partition, alpha and omega of the Linux system

14. Press OK after all that.

Comment: The Installation Type screen shows a completely empty panel without a single partition entry. Also, none of the button controls work, the "+", "-", or "Change". Thanks for the link to the tutorial though. I'm erasing the hard disk, and will try with an empty disk.